# Make: just link, skip compile

Tags: linux, makefile

I tried to build the Linux kernel recently. After hours and hours compiling everything, `make` failed during linking; `ld` just ran out of memory. I was wondering if there's a way such I could skip the whole compilation process directly into the linking step, since all the files have already been built.

Comment: Show us the actual commands involved. When compiling the linux kernel on Debian, I use `make menuconfig`, then `make -j 3` then perhaps `make-kpkg --initrd -j 3 binary`

Comment: I usually run `make oldconfig`, `make -j4`, `sudo make modules_install` and then `sudo make install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make should automatically take care of this as long as the timestamps of the source files have not advanced since the previous compilation. It *should* jump right to linking if you simply call make once more.

Comment: Well, when I ran `make` as a second try it just started compiling everything again (this time everything went well, but it didn't skip the compilation process as I wanted...)